# Split number and alphabets in string

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have strings like the ones below:

```
"22N"
"3X"
"-12X"
"12T"
"123123T"
```

Now, I want to split the `numbers` and `alphabets` to form an array of pairs:

```
[22, "N"]
[3, "X"]
[-12, "X"]
[12, "T"]
[123123, "T"]
```

What I tried:

```
var first = parseInt(input.substring(0, input.length - 1));
var last = input.slice(-1);
```

This works, but is there any faster way, because I have to process millions of data.

**Note**: `alphabets` are **single** character and **always last**.

Comment: Are you sure this is a resource bottleneck?

Comment: are the letters always after the number?

Comment: `"22N".match(/^(\d+)(\D+)$/)`

Comment: `str.split('\n').map(x => [x.slice(0,-1),x.slice(-1)])`

Comment: `str.match(/(-?\d+)([A-Z]+)/) .splice(1, 2)`

Comment: yupe numbers are always first , and character is just one and it is last.

Answer (score 6):

Well, `MDN` says next about the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

> unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number

If you believe it, you can take next approach:

```js
let tests = ["22N", "3X", "-12X", "12T", "123123T"];

const splitNumLetter = (str) => [+str.slice(0, -1), str.slice(-1)];

tests.forEach(s => console.log(splitNumLetter(s)));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

And maybe `str.charAt(str.length - 1)` is faster than `str.slice(-1)`. Here is a good performance comparison you can check: https://jsperf.com/charat-vs-index/5

Comment: Aahhh you were faster :(, `[parseInt(str.slice(0, a.length - 1)), str.slice(str.length - 1)]` was my way. You used some nice shorthands!

Answer (score 0):

This comes to my mind,

```
var str="22N";
str=str.split('');
var last = str.pop(); 
var last = str.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

By analyzing the pattern of your strings, numbers and letters are always left or right, never in the middle of the others. So, the fastest and code-cleanest way to achieve this is by using replace with regex.

The regex is necessary only once, since following this pattern I mention you can extract the numbers first and then just replace those extracted numbers from the same string.

Lets say you have your elements in an array variable:

```
var elements = [
    "22N",
    "3X",
    "-12X",
    "12T",
    "123123T"
];
```

And then, you just need to loop trough every of them, no matter how much elements are present, you can use the `forEach()` function after defining your final array:

```
var splitElements = [];
elements.forEach((string)=>{
    let numbers = string.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, ''),
        letters = string.replace(numbers,'');
   splitElements.push([numbers,letters])
});
```

And then you can see the result at `splitElements`. See how it works:

```js
var elements = [
 "22N",
  "3X",
 "-12X",
  "12T",
  "123123T"
],
  splitElements = [];

elements.forEach((string)=>{
 let numbers = string.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, ''),
    letters = string.replace(numbers,'');
   splitElements.push([numbers,letters])
});

console.log(splitElements);
```

Comment: I hope you don't really believe Regex is the fastest. Regex is slow.

Comment: @shadoe2020 Lol but you used regex in your answer too. I just gave another option, the fastest was already given and I upvoted it.